# Monotouch license

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to transfer my monotouch license to a new machine, so that I can code on that one instead. How can I go about doing that?

I cloned everything from my old mac to my new mac, now when I build in monodevelop I get the error:

Error 99: mtouch failed with the following message:
Invalid license.  Please reactivate MonoTouch
 (99)

I have a redownloaded monotouch and monodevelop, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: This can also happen after upgrading Windows (eg: Win7->Win8). In that case it seems to help to delete You'll need to remove the license file from:
%PROGRAMDATA%\MonoTouch\License\  and going back to VS, Tools -> Xamarin Store Account and reactivate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licensing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see this answer for a current solution:

[How do I reactivate Monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249568/how-do-i-reactivate-monotouch/11250980#11250980)

this original answer is obsolete

> Use the [Activation](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation) application
>
> /Developer/MonoTouch/Applications/MonoTouch Activation

Answer (score 7):

This worked in previous versions where the activation was separate from the Install, but now it is together with the installer, so if the above app is still there, run it, but that might be an older version.

To register now you'll have to remove the license file and re-run the setup. The license file is in ~/Library/MonoTouch and will have the name "License" or "License.v2" depending on the version of MonoTouch you have installed.

Answer (score 2):

The current (2012) error is "mtouch exited with code 99".

In addition to deleting the license file in ~/Library/MonoTouch, as noted by @Kenny, you may also need to delete the contents of /Developer/MonoTouch. If you don't do this, the MonoTouch installer may not do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has trouble with this:

1. Log in at xamarin.
2. Download your license file (think about creating a new on if you moved to another machine)
3. Open the Mac terminal
4. chflags nohidden ~/Library/
5. Open your user-home-directory in Finder.
6. NOW you can see the freakin' Library-folder.
7. After you placed the license-file there go back to terminal and use chflags hidden ~/Library/

For those of you who don't know where "~" comes from on Mac: Alt + N + Space!