# How do I reactivate Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I used the Apple MigrationAssistant to migrate to a new machine, and now MonoTouch won't launch my app in the simulator because it says my license is not valid. Following instructions in other posts here, I removed my license file and re-ran the setup, but that just told me that everything was installed and launched the app with the same problem. So, I completely removed MonoDevelop, and re-ran the setup. It dutifully downloaded MonoDevelop and installed it, but never gave me a chance to activate, so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.xamarin.com/

Look at the box that says "Product Download and Activation Self Service" - login there to re-download the full licensed version of MT.  There are also some tools to deal with reactivating licenses.

If all else fails, contact support directly.

Comment: Yeah, I found that page and re-downloaded the product. Re-installed, no dice. I've got a request out to support from the form on that site now, but they haven't responded yet.

Comment: The IRC chat turned out to be the best bet for me, guys in there got me sorted out quite nicely.